# Sending back a respond from wifi module?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

We have set the esp8266(wifi module) as a server(access point) and we send data to it from a browser/mobile phone.
Everything works great till the point where the esp has to send back the respond .
So, we send a GET request to the esp, ***and he always get the request***, ,but the browser/mobile is **not** getting his respond.

Here we set it as a server with :

```
AT+CIPMUX=1
OK
AT+CWMODE=3
OK
AT+CIPSERVER=1,80
OK
AT+CWSAP="myname","mypass",5,2
OK
```

The browser then connects to "myname" and send a get request :

```
http://192.168.4.1/setx:sety
```

the esp **gets it** and try to send a respond :

```
AT+CIPSEND=0,47
> HTTP/1.1 content \r\n Content-Type:text/xml\r\n
```

The respond is not seen by any browser! also tried

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n
```

Any idea ?

Comment: in AT mode esp works a little bit like proxy. There must be another mcu like arduino to answer. How do you know esp gets the GET request?

Comment: @MertGülsoy there shouldn't be any mcu to get the respond. with nodemcu lua, i can send and receive any type of respond . I know it gets the requests because i print it, and i always get it exactly as it being sent . and by the way , if i send many responds one after another, i do get them after a while ! something here is missing ..

Comment: you did not mention nodemcu in your question. It seems like AT mode being utilised. Anyway i suggest try to increase ap mode beacon interval like 3 seconds and follow the HTTP standars like headers and close conn.

Comment: @MertGülsoy thanks. its not with nodemcu its with AT . How do you "increase ap mode" ?? and whats the HTTP standards ? can you show me example? ( also seems that esp is ignoring all the carrier returns? )

Comment: For beaconing [check here](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/wiki/nodemcu_api_en#wifiapconfig) . For http communication try google or start from [here](https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/)

Comment: @MertGülsoy , well about google i have already heard, and the nodemcu link that you gave me i already know ( and as i stated i DONT use nodemcu)

Comment: well, in AT mode there is no way, in Arduino Mode possibly yes, in nodemcu mode I've sent it. In ESPSDK yes you can do with ` wiﬁ_softap_set_conﬁg`

Comment: @MertGülsoy I am sure you are wrong. Because in my example, as i already said, i have managed to send back a respond, but it only worked if i sent multiple responds one after another, with some strange http structure. so i guess i am doing something wrong and that it is possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92373/discussion-between-mert-gulsoy-and-curnelious).